# How can you put offline localstorage into MySQL with PDO/Mysqli?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I can store an image on `localstorage`.  I would like to be able to upload an image from localstorage to MySQL.  How would you pull this data and go from localstorage (or Sqlite) -> to MySQL (with mysqli or PDO) especially for pictures and PDF? I can't find tutorials anywhere for this or have the wrong keywords.

Basic HTML code as an example of Localstorage:

```
<div>
    <label for="image">Choose image:</label>
    <select id="image">
        <option value="images/firefoxos.png" selected>Firefox</option>
        <option value="images/tortoise.png">Tortoise</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var imgElem = document.querySelector('img');
var imageForm = document.getElementById('image');

function populateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('image', document.getElementById('image').value);
  setStyles();
}
function setStyles() {
  var currentImage = localStorage.getItem('image');
  document.getElementById('image').value = currentImage;
  imgElem.setAttribute('src', currentImage);
}

imageForm.onchange = populateStorage;
```

Comment: The closest thing I can find is http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/

Comment: In order to store anything in database on the sever side, you have to send something to PHP. Where in PHP the process is essentially routine and independent from the data origin. So your question is how to send a local storage contents to the server.

Comment: Would you make a variable from localstorage then just do a post or get from that?